# How to create a transparent layer to write text over a picture with html?

Tags: html, software-design, point-of-sale, opos

Could you guys please tell me how can I create a transparent layer over a product picture to be able to write the name and price of a product on sales screen of a Point of Sale software just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3GW.png) my problem is the text and price on the product picture aren't visible [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F0Mx.png)

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbHce.png) is the screen where I write the html code, I tried this code `<html><center><div style=background-color:#fafafa;color:#0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;>Product name` but the layer is [not transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L5Zs.png) and is not fitting the button, either it's to small or it's placement is incorrect, I wanted to be as I shared the pic above. Please let me know what can I do?

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I didn't write the <center>, when I go to edit the button section, this code is written initially, it comes with the software written like that. Anyway, can you please help me achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the background-color value to
`background-color:rgba(245,245,245,.2);`
the 0 value controls the alpha of the color, so 1 is opaque and 0 is translucent :)

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it's not working. What happened is that the entire background color changed to black and the 0 at the end doesn't have any effect, I tried putting other numbers but nothing is happening. What I'm trying to do is to have a layer that is transparent/with opacity so I can write description on it without hiding the entire part of the picture as it shown on the product screen of this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3GW.png)

Comment: Ok, that's my fault, it's `rgba` not `rgb`, will edit the answer.

Comment: This one worked but it only created a white layer that is not transparent/without opacity ([check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgOPi.png). I tried changing the last number (.2) to different numbers but it doesn't have any effect, you sure this is the one controlling the opacity?